# Ada GPS Install qtada

Tags: qt, qt4, ada

Set GNAT (usr/gnat/) and Qt 4 (/usr/bin/designer-qt4)

Then, I followed the installation steps of QtAda (/home/ebanat/Files/Ada/qtada)
When configuring, an error
./configure --prefix=/usr/

checking whether QT_NO_ACCESSIBILITY is declared... no
checking for gprconfig... no
configure: error: gprconfig not found

What could be the problem?

Comment: Comment not answer because wild guess: gprconfig is not part of Gnat, but part of gprbuild. You need to `apt-get install gprbuild`, either as a separate component (if it's separately available), or possibly `apt-get install gps` as gprbuild is usually distributed with the GPS IDE.

Comment: Thank you, once installed (sudo apt-get install gprbuild) all earned